# compare two files' contents extracting different contents in python

Tags: python

I have two files, file1 contains contents as

> aaa
>
> bbb
>
> ccc

and file 2 contains contents as

> ccc
>
> ddd
>
> eee
>
> aaa
>
> rrr
>
> bbb
>
> nnn

I would like to do like this, if file2 contains file1's line, then that line would be removed from file2. At last, file2 will be as ddd
                                      eee
                                      rrr
                                      nnn
Besides, my code is

```
f1 = open("test1.txt","r")
f2 = open("test2.txt","r")

    fileOne = f1.readlines()
    fileTwo = f2.readlines()
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
    outFile = open("test.txt","w")
    x = 0
    for i in fileOne:
        if i !=  fileTwo[x]:
            outFile.writelines(fileTwo[x])
        x += 1

outFile.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that you have asked a question (there's no ? that I can see).  We need to know what you want us to help you with.

Comment: I will say that you probably want `outfile.write` instead of `outfile.writelines`.  `writelines` expects a list of strings, but you appear to be passing just a string.

Comment: Post with correct indentation, please.

Answer (score 4):

```
with open("f1.txt") as f1:
    s1 = set(f1)
with open("f2.txt") as f2, open("f3.txt","w") as f3:
    f3.writelines(x for x in f2 if x not in s1)
```

It's good practice to use a context manager to close the file (this is what the `with` does).

It's much more efficient to check for membership of a `set` than a `list`

If there is a possibility of extra whitespace, you should strip the lines like this

```
with open("f1.txt") as f1:
    s1 = set(x.strip() for x in f1)
with open("f2.txt") as f2, open("f3.txt","w") as f3:
    f3.writelines(x for x in f2 if x.strip() not in s1)
```

Comment: Wow, much better than mine answer. +1 :)  Quicker too!  Although I was under the impression that python would close a file during garbage collection if it was open for read only, right?

Comment: @Nater, files get closed when they are garbage collected, but it's not always as soon as they go out of scope - eg for jython. It's better to clean them up so you don't waste resources and risk running out of open files.

Comment: The line "aaa" still exits. Thanks.I'd like to remove the line which exits in file1.

Comment: @MY_1129, perhaps the line isn't an exact match. Is there extra spaces or something?

Comment: I think exactly not compare the lines, it should be compared the strings. So, if the strings exits in the file1, then it would be removed from file2. There is no extra spaces or others.

Answer (score 0):

Use set difference to find the differences of the two files.

```
f1 = open("test1.txt","r").readlines()
f2 = open("test2.txt","r").readlines()

diff = set(f2) - set(f1)
outFile = open("test.txt","w")
outFile.writelines(line for line in f2 if line in diff)
```

Comment: why would you not pass `diff` directly to writelines instead of `line for line in f2 if line in diff`

Comment: The line "aaa" still exits. Thanks.I'd like to remove the line which exits in file1.

Comment: sets are unordered, and items in sets are unique.  If the output must remain ordered, or has duplicates, use something like above, otherwise, you can pass the set into writelines

Answer (score 0):

Using your code...

```
f1 = open("test1.txt","r").read()
f2 = open("test2.txt","r").read()

fileOne = f1.splitlines()
fileTwo = f2.splitlines()

# remove the dup lines
nodup_lines = [line for line in fileTwo if line not in fileOne]
# join using newline character
newFileTwo = '\n'.join(nodup_lines)

# write file
outFile = open("test.txt","w")
outFile.write(newFileTwo)
outFile.close()
```

Comment: The line "aaa" still exits. Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to remove the line which exits in file1.

Comment: All three of these answers should work for you.  Can you copy and past an exact copy of the file.  There must be a tab newline or some type of whitespace character still in the file.